# PHP merge two arrays with same key and output to specific json format

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My database has two tables. One is calling out the book info and another is calling image info. I would like to merge these two table data into one JSON. If the img id is matched with the data id, then the image is belongs to this book. I tried to use foreach to loop the book data into array and use another foreach to loop the image data within the book data array, but failed to get the expected result.

Book Table JSON:

```
{
 "data": [
    {
        "id": 17,
        "author": "Belcurls",
        "bookname": "You Never Know"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "author": "Carolina",
        "bookname": "A Story Teller"
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "author": "Lokas",
        "bookname": "The Love"
    }
 ]
}
```

Image Table JSON:

```
{
"img": [
    {
        "id": 18,
        "url": "image18.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "url": "image18b.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "url": "image19.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "url": "image19b.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "url": "image19c.png"
    }
]
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{
 "data": [
    {
        "id": 17,
        "author": "Belcurls",
        "bookname": "You Never Know"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "author": "Carolina",
        "bookname": "A Story Teller",
        "image":[
           {
             "url":"image18"
           },
           {
             "url":"image18b"
           }
         ]
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "author": "Lokas",
        "bookname": "The Love",
        "image":[
           {
             "url":"image19"
           },
           {
             "url":"image19b"
           },
           {
             "url":"image19c"
           }
         ]
    }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: have you tried using `array_merge`? Can you post your code?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo Link**](https://3v4l.org/U4fOC).

You can do this loop, Please check inline doc for explanation

```
foreach ($arr['data'] as $key => &$value) { // & to update changes as its address
    foreach ($imgs['img'] as $key1 => $value1) {
        if($value['id'] == $value1['id']){ // checking if match id of parent with images
            $value['image'][] = ['url' => $value1['url']]; // then simply push
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to convert your json to php array use

```
 json_decode($yourjson, true); // second parameter is for converting it to array else it will convert into object.
```

Comment: simple and easy understand answer. I never think to use & to update the changes, that why i can't get the expected result.

Comment: yes, your answer solved my problem and teach me a good lesson

Answer (score 0):

If you make the data array associative then you only need to loop the image array and add them to the correct subarray in data.

```
// This flattens the array and makes it associative
$data = array_column($data['data'], null, 'id');

foreach($img['img'] as $v){
    $data[$v['id']]['image'][] = ['url' => $v['url']];
}
// Add the 'data' again
$final['data'] = array_values($data);

var_dump($final);
echo json_encode($final);
```

https://3v4l.org/736lQ